# form details are stored into the database but will make an automatic logout laravel 5.3

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I created a FORM to add employee using laravel 5.3. 
when I fill the details and submit form ,all the data are inserted into the database.
but after save values automatically logout.
I can't find any solution for that issue.Please help me to fix this problem.[this is ajax call result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNVYk.jpg)

form-validation.js

```
submitHandler: function(form) {

    var loading_el = $('#AddEmp');
    setLoader(loading_el, true);
    var userLevelId = $('#AddUserLevel').find('option:selected').attr('data-id');
    var policyId = $('#AddPolicies').find('option:selected').attr('data-id');

    $.ajax({
            url:'/addEmployee',
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                    email: $("#AddEmail").val(),
                    password: $("#AddEmpPassword").val(),
                    confirmPassword: $("#AddEmpConfirmPassword").val(),
                    EmpNo01: $("#AddEmpNo01").val(),
                    EmpNo02: $("#AddEmpNo02").val(),
                    UserLevel:userLevelId ,                 
                    Designation:$("#Designation").val(),    
                    Policies: policyId,      
                    FirstName: $("#AddFname").val(),
                    LastName: $("#AddLname").val(),
                    telephone: $("#AddTp").val(),
                    Mobile: $("#AddMno").val(),
                    JoinDate: $("#AddJoinDate").val(),
                    dob: $("#Adddob").val()

                },
```

web.php

```
   Route::group(['middleware'=>['admin']],function(){ // start admin routes
    Route::post('/addEmployee','web\EmployeeController@AddEmployeeDetails');
   }
```

EmployeeController.php

```
class EmployeeController extends Controller{

private $Employee;
private $policies;
private $Role;
private $Users;
private $EmployeeLeavePolicy;

public function __construct(EmployeeRepository $Employee ,LeavePolicyRepository $policies, RoleRepository $Role, UserRepository $Users,EmployeeLeavePolicyRepository $EmployeeLeavePolicy)
{
    $this->Employee = $Employee;
    $this->policies = $policies;
    $this->Role = $Role;
    $this->Users = $Users;
    $this->EmployeeLeavePolicy = $EmployeeLeavePolicy;

}

public function AddEmployeeDetails(addEmployeeRequest $request)
{
    try
    {
       $dataUser=[    //this data save in users table
            'name'=>$request['FirstName'],
            'email'=>$request['email'],
            'user_type'=>$request['UserLevel'],
            'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),

        ];

         $responseUser=$this->Users->create($dataUser);   //this is working one
        $res=$responseUser->id;

        if($responseUser)
        {
            $dataEmployee=[
                       'email'=>$request['email'],
                       'company_id'=>1,
                       'userId'=>$res,
                       'user_level'=>$request['UserLevel'],
                       'designation'=>$request['Designation'],
                       'empNo1'=>$request['EmpNo01'],
                       'empNo2'=>$request['EmpNo02'],
                       'password' => Hash::make($request['password']),
                       'first_name'=>$request['FirstName'],
                       'last_name'=>$request['LastName'],
                       'telephone'=>$request['telephone'],
                       'mobile'=>$request['Mobile'],
                       'join_date'=>$request['JoinDate'],
                       'dob'=>$request['dob'],
                       'status'=>1,
                ];

            $responseEmployee=$this->Employee->create($dataEmployee);

            if($responseEmployee)
            {
                $employeeId=$responseEmployee->id;  //get employee id
                $leaveId=$request['Policies'];      //get leave policy id

                $dataEmpLeavePolicy=[
                    'employee_Id'=>$employeeId,
                    'leave_policy_id'=>$leaveId,
                ];

                $responseLeavePolicy=$this->EmployeeLeavePolicy->create($dataEmpLeavePolicy);


            }

        Config::post('messages.ADD_USER_SUCCESS')];
            return ['success'=>'true','message'=> 'Data Added'];
        }
        else
        {
            return ['success'=>'false', 'error'=>Config::get('messages.ADD_USER_ERROR')];
        }
    }
    catch (Exception $ex)
    {
        return ['success'=>'false', 'error'=>  $ex->getMessage()];
    }
```

Employee.php

```
  class Employee extends Model{

         protected $fillable=[
                              'userId',
                              'company_id',
                              'empNo1',
                              'empNo2',
                              'user_level',       
                              'designation',        
                              'first_name',
                              'last_name',
                              'email',
                              'password',
                              'telephone',
                              'mobile',
                              'join_date',
                              'dob',
                              'status'
                           ];


     }
```

Comment: Please share all your controller, or at least the full method. Looking at your code now, we can't really see anything, looks, good, but you should have more code being responsible for the problem

Comment: @AntonioCarlosRibeiro is it ok to add big code lines in stack?there are some big code lines.

Answer (score 1):

It's strange that it logs you out, but instead of returning an array on success/failure (since you are making an AJAX call), return a response with json instead.

`return response()->json(['success'=>'true','message'=> 'Data Added']);`

Comment: You will also save yourself and other developers a lot of frustration by keeping your naming conventions consistent...